# How to use a secondary delimiter for every 6th string generated by using split function on a primary delimiter in Python?

Tags: python, file, split

I have a pipe delimited file that ends a record with a newline delimiter after every 6 pipe delimited fields as follows.

```
uid216|Banana
bunches
nurture|Fail|76|7645|Singer

uid342|Orange
vulture|Pass|56
87|3547|Actor
```

I was using split function in python to convert the records in the file to a list of strings.

```
  parts = file_str.split('|')
```

However, I don't seem to understand how I can use a newline character as delimiter for every 6th string alone. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you just want to remove the `\n` at the end of each line, perhaps `parts = file_str.rstrip("\n").split("|")`?

Comment: @wkl If I understand correctly, `file_str = open(filename).read()`, not `for file_str in open(filename)`

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to read one line at a time from the file instead of reading the entire thing all at once.

Comment: I don't understand the update. This is a totally different data layout, isn't it? That invalidates the existing answers. And the fields seem to be in groups of 8, not 6, no?

Comment: Oh, they are in groups of 6, but some of them contain newlines. That's annoying. Where is this data coming from? Could you try to get a cleaner version, like maybe in JSON format instead of this pseudo-CSV format?

Comment: @wjandrea .. This is a dummy version of the dataset I have. I cannot disclose information about the actual dataset though. This is the only version of the dataset I have for now.

Answer (score 1):

The *right* way to do this is probably to use Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for reading delimited files and stream the data from the file rather than reading it all into memory at once. When you read the whole file into a string you essentially have to iterate over it twice.

```
import csv

def process_file(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file_handle:
        reader = csv.Reader(file_handle, delimiter='|')
        for row in reader:
            # row is a list whose entries are the fields of the delimited row;
            # do what you want with it.
```

Comment: FYI, OP updated the question, invalidating this answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the words can span multiple lines between the pipes.

You could read the whole file, and then use a pattern to match 5 times a pip char with all the preceding and following words.

```
^[^|\n]+(?:\n?[^|\n]+)*(?:\|[^|\n]+(?:\n?[^|\n]+)*){5}
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^|\n]+` Match 1+ chars other than `|` or a newline
- `(?:\n?[^|\n]+)*` Optionally match an optional newline and 1+ chars other than `|` or a newline
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\|[^|\n]+` Match `|` and 1+ chars other than `|` or a newline
  - `(?:\n?[^|\n]+)*` Optionally repeat an optional newline and 1+ chars other than `|` or a newline
- `){5}` Close the non capture group and repeat it 5 times to match 5 pipe chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FAmiuW/1)

For example

```
import re

file = open('file', mode='r')

allText = file.read()
pattern = r"^[^|\n]+(?:\n?[^|\n]+)*(?:\|[^|\n]+(?:\n?[^|\n]+)*){5}"

file.close()

for s in re.findall(pattern, allText, re.M):
    print(s.split("|"))
```

Output

```
['uid216', 'Banana\nbunches\nnurture', 'Fail', '76', '7645', 'Singer']
['uid342', 'Orange\nvulture', 'Pass', '56\n87', '3547', 'Actor']
```

If there have to be either 2 newlines following or the end of the string:

```
^[^|\n]+(?:\n?[^|\n]+)*(?:\|[^|\n]+(?:\n?[^|\n]+)*){5}(?=\n\n|\Z)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BP3ME3/1)

Answer (score 0):

```py
parts = []

#iterate over each line by using split on \n
# extend to gather all strings in a single list
for line in file_str.split("\n"):
    parts.extend(line.split("|"))

print(parts)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, it's better to provide an explanation. See [answer].

Comment: Oh wait, `parts(...)` is wrong. I think you want `parts.append(...)`. But then, why not do a comprehension like in [my answer](/a/73431367/4518341)?